# ¿Cómo adjuntar archivos en email?

Tags: python, tkinter, smtp, listbox

Actualmente mi código es capaz de enlistar archivos (en la ventana principal) y enviar el nombre del archivo a través de la interfaz del correo electrónico, pero no aparece el archivo adjunto. ¿cómo puedo enviar un archivo adjunto previamente seleccionado a partir de un listbox?

He estado buscando soluciones y leyendo algunos artículos, pero debido a mi inexperiencia en programación, es muy difícil y no tan claro para mi llevar al cabo este proceso, por lo tanto, cualquier consejo me ayudaría mucho, gracias.

Este es un ejemplo de mi código donde se puede mostrar los archivos al presionar “enter”. El botón “enviar” es el encargado de abrir la interfaz del correo electrónico:

```
    def agregar_menu(self): 
        menubar1 = tk.Menu(self.ventana1)   
        self.ventana1.geometry("400x400")   
        self.ventana1.config(menu=menubar1) 
        menubar1.add_command(label="Enviar", command=self.enviar)   
        self.entry= tk.Entry(self.ventana1, width=45)   
        self.entry.pack()   
        self.ventana1.bind("<Return>", lambda x:searchfiles(self.entry.get(), '../'))   
    
        self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.ventana1)     
        self.lb.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, expand = YES, fill = "both") 
        self.lb.bind("<Double-Button>", lambda x: open_file())  
    
        #funcion para buscar archivos 
        def searchfiles(extension='.txt', folder='C:\\'):   
            "insertar documentos"   
            [self.lb.insert(0, r + "\\" + file) for r, d, f in os.walk(folder) for file in f  if file.endswith(extension)]  
        #funcion para abrir archivos
        def open_file():    
            os.startfile(self.lb.get(self.lb.curselection()[0]))    
    #funcion para abrir la interfaz del correo electronico 
    def enviar(self):   
        dialogo1=self.toplevel(self.ventana1)   
        s=dialogo1()    
    
    def toplevel (self, ventanaprincipal):  
        root=tk.Toplevel(ventanaprincipal)  
        root.title('Enviar a...')   
        root.geometry('500x660')    
        Label_1=Label(root, text="Correo:", width=20, font=("bold",10)) 
        Label_1.place(x=40,y=110)   
        Rmail=StringVar()   
        Rpswrd=StringVar()  
        Rsender=StringVar() 
        Rsubject=StringVar()    
        emailE=Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=Rmail)    
        emailE.place(x=200, y=110)  
        Label_2=Label(root, text="Contraseña:", width=20, font=("bold",10)) 
        Label_2.place(x=40,y=160)   
        passwordE=Entry(root, width=40, show="*", textvariable=Rpswrd)  
        passwordE.place(x=200, y=160)   
        Label_3=Label(root, text="Enviar a:", width=20, font=("bold",10))   
        Label_3.place(x=40,y=260)   
        senderE=Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=Rsender) 
        senderE.place(x=200, y=260) 
        Label_4=Label(root, text="Asunto:", width=20, font=("bold",10)) 
        Label_4.place(x=40,y=310)   
        subjectE=Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=Rsubject)   
        subjectE.place(x=200, y=310)    
        Label_5=Label(root, text="Mensaje:", width=20, font=("bold",10))    
        Label_5.place(x=40,y=360)   
        msgbodyE=Text(root, width=30, height=10)    
        msgbodyE.place(x=200, y=360)    
    
        #funcion para enviar email
        def sendemail():    
            try:    
                mymsg=MIMEMultipart()   
                mymsg['From']=str(Rmail.get())  
                mymsg['To']= str(Rsender.get()) 
                mymsg['Subject']= str(Rsubject.get())   
                mymsg.attach(MIMEText(msgbodyE.get(1.0,'end'), 'plain'))    
                server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)  
                server.starttls()   
                server.login(str(Rmail.get()), str(Rpswrd.get()))   
                text=mymsg.as_string()  
                server.sendmail(str(Rmail.get()), str(Rsender.get()), text) 
                Label_6=Label(root, text="Done!", width=20,fg='green', font=("bold",15))    
                Label_6.place(x=140,y=550)  
                server.quit()   
            except: 
                Label_6=Label(root, text="something went wrong!", width=20,fg='red', font=("bold",15))  
                Label_6.place(x=140,y=550)  

        #funcion de adjuntar archivos     
        def selection():
            global filename,filetype,filepath,check
            check=True
            filename=os.path.basename(self.lb.get(self.lb.curselection()[0]))
            msgbodyE.insert(END,f'\n{filename}\n')
    
        sendbtn = Button(root, text='Enviar', bg='black', fg='white', width = 10, command=sendemail).place(x=140,y=550) 
        btn = Button(root, text='Seleccionar', bg='black', fg='white', width = 10,command= selection).place(x=250,y=550)    
    
        root.mainloop() 
aplicacion1=Aplicacion()
```

estas son las funciones necesarias para llevar a cabo el proceso

```
#funcion para listar y seleccionar archivos
self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.ventana1)  
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.ventana1, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.ventana1, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.lb.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y) 
        self.lb.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, expand = YES, fill = "both")
        self.lb.bind("<Double-Button>", lambda x: open_file())

        def searchfiles(extension='.txt', folder='C:\\'):
            "insertar documentos"
            [self.lb.insert(0, r + "\\" + file) for r, d, f in os.walk(folder) for file in f  if file.endswith(extension)]
```

```
#funcion para enviar archivos adjuntos
 def seleccion():
            global filename,filetype,filepath,check
            check=True
            filename=os.path.basename(self.lb.get(self.lb.curselection()[0]))
            en_message.insert(END,f'\n{filename}\n')
```

Comment: yo no veo en ninguna parte como elaboras el mensaje

Comment: Gracias, ya he corregido mi pregunta